# Does Traefik take care of the initial "Let's encrypt" authentication and renewal?

Tags: traefik

In order to get a SSL certificate for a website’s domain from Let’s Encrypt, I have to demonstrate control over the domain. The Let’s Encrypt CA will look at the domain name being requested and issue one or more sets of challenges.

**Q1**: When I have a domain name pointing to a VPS and an e-mail address at Let's encrypt, can Traefik automatically take care of the initial authentication process?

**Q2**: Is it sufficient to keep the http (80) port open for Let's encrypt for the initial validation?

**Q3**: Does automatic renewal requires the 80 port to be open? Or could this also be a 443 port? It is much better to start redirecting all traffic to https from now on. SO - can  Traefik/LetsEncrypt can automatically renew using the 443 port open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers (so far):

**Q1: YES!** The e-mail can be just any e-mail address you have. The domain name does not have to be the same as your domain name. The domain name should, indeed, point to the VPS.

**Q2: YES!** For the first time, leave the 80 port open. Start redirecting after the certificate is installed.

**Q3: YES!**: I couldn't find an answer, so I immediately tried the suggestions given in the first answer. I restarted about 3 times, due to changing other settings, and no errors were shown in the Traefik logging.

Now let's move on to the real code. In the code you can find the 3 answers. The next file is the traefik.toml file:

```
logLevel = "ERROR"
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
  [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
    address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]

[docker]
  domain = "xyz.com"

[api]

[acme]
  # Q1 - just use your email address
  email = "email@example.com"
  storage = "acme.json"
  onHostRule = true
  entryPoint = "https"
  # Q3 answer = this allows for the TLS challenge on port 443
  [acme.tlsChallenge]
  # Q2 answer = this provides the HTTP challenge on port 80
  #[acme.httpChallenge]
  #  entryPoint = "http"
```

The docker-compose file is:

```
version: '3'
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v1.7
    container_name: traefik
    restart: always
    networks:
      - yourappnet
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /your_path/traefik/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
      - /your_path/traefik/acme.json:/acme.json
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    labels:
      - "traefik.docker.network=yourappnet"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:monitor.xyz.com"
      - "traefik.port=8080"

  yourapp:
    image: dockerhubuser/dockerimagename:latest
    ports:
      - 8080
    networks:
      - yourappnet
    labels:
      - "traefik.docker.network=yourappnet"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:xyz.com"

networks:
  yourappnet:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 2):

**Q2 and Q3:**

The port used to resolve the Let's Encrypt challenge (creation or renewal) depends of which challenge you are using:

- For the HTTP challenge, you need to use the port 80
- For the TLS-ALPN Challenge, you need to the port 443
- For the DNS challenge, no port is required because the validation process on DNS server.

The creation or the renewal use the same port (depends of the challenge), so if you want that Traefik renew automatically your certificate you need to leave the port open.

Comment: Today I started with the http-challenge. Can I switch to the TLS-ALPN challenge?

Comment: yes but you will have to restart Traefik: the acme configuration is part of the static configuration, which will require a restart of Traefik for this to be taken into account.